# Polymer 1.0: polymer-element not showing

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The below code does not show in the browser. This works in Polymer 0.5. Is there code difference as I am using 1.0?:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="my-name">
  <template>
    <h1> Hello {{name}}</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-name', {
      ready: function() {
        this.name = "Brown";
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Yes there are significant differences between 0.5 and 1.0. I would go as far to say they're essentially not compatible from my experience upgrading. Check this: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but dude you really need to start by reading https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html before asking. **Don't be lazy!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to rewrite your element based on the new requirements. You can easily follow it in the [migration guide, registration element section](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration).

You should rewrite it like following:

```html
<dom-module id="my-name">
  <template>
    <!--Keep in mind in polymer 1.0 you can't have whitespaces in bound tags-->
    <h1>Hello <span>{{name}}</span></h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-name", 
      ready: function () {
        this.name = "Brown";
      }
    });
  </script>  
</dom-module>
```

I did a [Plunker where you can reproduce it](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ff9AiB?p=preview).

Comment: I'll try this later as I've left my laptop at home. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: need to import following line  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-name">
  <style>
    /*your styles go here*/
  <style>
  <template>
    <!-- Things to show in element view -->
    <h1> Hello <span>{{name}}</span></h1>
  </template>
<dom-module>
  <script>
    // Your script goes here
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-name',
      
        properties: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                value: 'Brown'
            }
        }
      });
  </script>
```

There are many differences when migrating from Polymer 0.5 to Polymer 1.0 +. They changed the old `polymer-element` to `dom-module` and `name` attribute to `id`. The constructor is also changed as i shown in the example. Read https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html to get more info on migrating.

Answer (score 0):

polymer 1.0 changes `<polymer-element name="my-name"> to <dom-module id="my-name">.`

I think you should follow the documentation of polymer 1.0

[Polymer 1.0 documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/)